# DNN Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object error occurs in live site when i edit content

Tags: dotnetnuke

When I try to edit content of page using HTML module of DNN in ny site (Live now), this 
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

please select Admin-->Event Viewer to see what the details exception information about.And add a more detailed description for this question. Then others will offer an effective help.